# Enable / Disable submit button on a dropkick enabled form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-dropkick

I have a form styled with jQuery's [Dropkick](http://jamielottering.github.com/DropKick/)  however I'm unable enable / disable a submit button once the forms get the style. The JS validation works as expected without Dropkick.

The HTML:

```
<form method="get" id="dropkickform" action="">
    <select id="min" class="list">
        <option selected="selected" value="">Selection 1</option>
        <option value="1">100</option>
        <option value="2">200</option>
    </select>

    <select id="max" class="list">
        <option selected="selected" value="">Selection 2</option>
        <option value="1">500</option>
        <option value="2">600</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

The JS:

```
$('.list').dropkick();

$(document).ready(function () {
    $form = $('#dropkickform');
    $form.find(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
    $form.find(':input').change(function () {
        var disable = false;
        $form.find(':input').not('[type="submit"]').each(function (i, el) {
            if ($.trim(el.value) === '') {
                disable = true;
            }
        });
        $form.find(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', disable);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L3FCV/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see once you apply dropkick it will not update the `select`s behind the scenes so your validation will not work because of that (the `select`s have the initial option selected all the time, have a look in firebug/chrome web inspector to see it).

I've been able to get close with http://jsfiddle.net/Qguh5/ but it does break sometimes.

I used:

```
$('.list').dropkick({
    change: function(value, label){
        var disable = true;

        $('.dk_option_current > a').each(function(){
            if($(this).data('dk-dropdown-value')){
                disable = false;
            } else {
                disable = true;
            }
        });

        $form.find(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled',disable);
    }
});
```

The `change` event is mentioned on the dropkick page.

I suggest you give http://uniformjs.com a try if you want custom looking forms. It might not be as pretty as dropkick but it is a lot easier to use in your scenario.

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to have a look and for your alternative plugin suggestion.